# Unordered_map values from CSV file

Tags: c++, csv, c++11, unordered-map

I have found an example of something similar that I am trying to implement:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string,std::string> mymap = {
  {"us","United States"},
  {"uk","United Kingdom"},
  {"fr","France"},
  {"de","Germany"}
};
```

However, the values that I have are in a CSV file.

Would I need to insert these values into a different container and then add them to the unordered_map or is it possible to add them straight from the file?

I'm struggling to figure it out so at the moment I am just writing the file content out to the screen:

```
int menuLoop = 1;
int userChoice;
string getInput;

while(menuLoop == 1)
{
    cout << "Menu\n\n" 
         << "1. 20\n"
         << "2. 100\n"
         << "3. 500\n"
         << "4. 1000\n"
         << "5. 10,000\n"
         << "6. 50,000\n\n";
    cin >> userChoice;

    if(userChoice == 1)
    {
        cout << "\n20\n\n";
        string getContent;
        ifstream openFile("20.txt");
        if(openFile.is_open())
        {
            while(!openFile.eof())
            {
                getline(openFile, getContent);
                cout << getContent << endl;
            }
        }
        system("PAUSE"); 
    }
}
```

The contents of the file:

```
Bpgvjdfj,Bvfbyfzc
Zjmvxouu,Fsmotsaa
Xocbwmnd,Fcdlnmhb
Fsmotsaa,Zexyegma
Bvfbyfzc,Qkignteu
Uysmwjdb,Wzujllbk
Fwhbryyz,Byoifnrp
Klqljfrk,Bpgvjdfj
Qkignteu,Wgqtalnh
Wgqtalnh,Coyuhnbx
Sgtgyldw,Fwhbryyz
Coyuhnbx,Zjmvxouu
Zvjxfwkx,Sgtgyldw
Czeagvnj,Uysmwjdb
Oljgjisa,Dffkuztu
Zexyegma,Zvjxfwkx
Fcdlnmhb,Klqljfrk
Wzujllbk,Oljgjisa
Byoifnrp,Czeagvnj
```

Comment: Can you show us what your file `20.txt` looks like?

Comment: @us2012 it's at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract your data, use a CSV parser library or manually split each line of the file using a comma as the delimiter. CSV files are no different than text files; they just follow a distinctive data format.

An intermediate data structure is unnecessary. Assuming your data is in the format `[key],[value]`, use the C++ documentation for unordered_map [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/operator%5B%5D/) to properly insert your data.

Example:

```
string line;
getline(file, line);

// simple split (alternatively, use strtok)
string key = line.substr(0,line.find(','));
string value = line.substr(line.find(',')+1);

unordered_map<string,string> mymap;
mymap[key] = value;
```

Edit: us2012's method of [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) with a delimiter is also particularly useful. Also keep in mind that attention must be paid when reading CSV's with delimiters as data, often indicated by values surrounded by quotes:

```
"hello, world","hola","mundo"
```

More information on CSV formats can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).

Answer (score 2):

You can directly specify delimiters in `getline`.

```
        while(true)
        {
            string key, value;
            //try to read key, if there is none, break
            if (!getline(openFile, key, ',')) break;
            //read value
            getline(openFile, value, '\n');
            mymap[key] = value;
            cout << key << ":" << value << endl;
        }
```

Note that your current loop checks too late whether you're at the end of the file and will produce an empty key,value pair. This is corrected above.